# Angular Material - Empty Badge

Tags: angular, angular-material, badge

I'm currently adding badges to the buttons of the menu of my application, which already works fine. I want to display the number of notifications the user still has to look at like this:

```
<span matBadge="4" matBadgeColor="warn">Look at these notifications!</span>
```

On a mobile phone though, the menu is hidden behind a burger icon. I don't want the user to show how many notifications he has on top of this icon. I only want him to know that he has some, and when he opens the menu, he will see a badge with the number of notifications on the various buttons.

My problem is that an empty badge is always hidden. I can't seem to show it like this:

```
<span matBadge="" matBadgeColor="warn">Look at these notifications!</span>
```

Is it not possible at all to show an empty badge? Am I missing something, or is this behaviour by design?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will have to add a class for yourself to hide the text. The mat-badge has no functionality to hide the content. White space or `&nbsp;` will not work:

```
.mat-badge.hide-text .mat-badge-content {
  color: transparent;
}

<span matBadge="0" matBadgeColor="warn" class="hide-text">Look at these notifications!</span>
```

Update:

If you really don't want to use a class, you can use the `&#8288;`. This is a so called [WORD JOINER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner). Mileage may vary with Angular version :), but this will print an empty badge

```
<span matBadge="&#8288;" matBadgeColor="warn">Look at these notifications!</span>
```

Comment: Do you guys think there is a reason, why it is not possible by default to show an empty badge? Could there be a mistake in my design, if I think I need one?

Comment: What's the reason you do not want to show the number of notifications. That's a bit unclear to me, but if you are certain this is the way you want to show it.. then.. this is the way to go :)

Comment: Lets take Facebook as an example and imagine I group the Friends-, Messages- and Notification-Button under one single burger menu. I then want to show the user that something happened and show the badge. Showing a 10 inside (as in 3 friend requests, 2 messages and 5 new posts) won't be of any use, since the user can't interpret the number anyway, until he opens the menu. But showing that something happened is still important.

Comment: That makes sense, and to me an empty badge is information enough. I didn't know you had multiple badges. I believe the empty badge is used in several popular designs

Comment: For me it would make sense when you think about using it with a binding. If you have e.g. `[matBadge]="variable"`, you can easily switch off the badge, if you just set `variable = ""` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 16):

Use `[matBadgeHidden] = "true"` for dynamically control visibility of `matBadge`, 
e.g.:

```
<span [matBadgeHidden] = "commentCount == 0"  [matBadge]="commentCount" matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgeOverlap="false">Comments</span>
```

Comment: -1 because this is not related to the question being asked. The question is to be able to explicitly show a badge with empty content. The Badge component by default will hide the badge if the content is empty, i.e. `matBadge` value is empty, regardless of the value of `matBadgeHidden`.

Comment: `matbadgehidden` is present in the docs as well, don't know why but this directive is not hiding the badge upon some condition, please let me know if someone else faces the same issue

Comment: me too @AwaisNasir - how did you get along with this?

Answer (score 4):

In looking at the [source for the badge component](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/badge/badge.ts#L87), it looks like this is by design due to lines:

```
'[class.mat-badge-hidden]': 'hidden || !_hasContent',
...
this._hasContent = value != null && `${value}`.trim().length > 0;
```

It does look like you can use `matBadge="&#8203;"` to have an empty badge show to work around this.

Answer (score 3):

You can add below css to display empty badge.

```
.mat-badge-hidden .mat-badge-content:empty {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Have a look on below example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-badge-with-pipe

Comment: Still works in Angular 9 - just be sure that you pass null, not an empty string into [matBadge]